# 403 Forbidden when accessing image in wordpress

Tags: images, uploads

I am getting 403 Fobidden error when trying to access directly from URL.

Here is my blog page url : http://www.modestmoney.com/peer-lending-returns-still-sizzling/

Images are displaying in post details page correctly but when i am trying to access the same image directly from url like below then it will giving me 403 Forbidden Error http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Peer-Lending1.jpg

When we right click on the post image and open image in new tab then it will be opened as below:

http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Peer-Lending1.jpg?1a2ec8

So the images are accessible when we add ?1a2ec8 parameter but i dont know why its added automatically?

My upload directory has 0755 permission and all the images have 0644 permission. I have installed W3TC plugin.

Can you please advise me on this what should i do to access images directly from the url like: http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Peer-Lending1.jpg

Here is my `.htaccess` file code

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    .
    .
    .
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    .
    .
    .
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
         Header unset Set-Cookie
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
         Header unset Set-Cookie
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymlinks
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType application/javascript .js2
.
.
.
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
.
.
.
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>      

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RedirectMatch 301 /main.php$ http://www.modestmoney.com/
RedirectMatch 301 /thank-you/$ http://www.modestmoney.com/
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)reviewRead$ http://www.modestmoney.com/
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)/Apply$ http://www.modestmoney.com/$1/
rewritecond %{http_host} ^modestmoney.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.modestmoney.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*default\.htm\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)default\.htm$ http://www.modestmoney.com/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png)$">
Header set Last-Modified "Wed, 14 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|gif|js|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.css" "$1\.css\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.js" "$1\.js\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header append Content-Encoding gzip

      # Force proxies to cache gzipped &
      # non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# BEGINNING of EXPIRES
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A300
ExpiresByType text/html A5
ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType text/css A604800
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A604800
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
ExpiresByType text/plain A300
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A604800
ExpiresByType video/x-flv A604800
ExpiresByType application/pdf A604800
# END of EXPIRES
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://modestmoney.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://modestmoney.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://old.modestmoney.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://old.modestmoney.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.modestmoney.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.modestmoney.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.old.modestmoney.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.old.modestmoney.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]

# Browser Caching

FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule expires_module>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpe "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-httpd-php-source "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think there is something preventing from folder/directory permission or from .Htaccess. What is files and folder permissions you have given for wp-content and it's files?

Comment: @HelpingHands all folders have 0755 and files have 0644 permission

Comment: I see , that seems fine then. can you please put your  .Htaccess code here?

Comment: @HelpingHands htaccess code added to question please check

Comment: Htaccess code looks fine to me. Do one thing , Just take backup of this htaccess file , create new one with only code  `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress `  and then check for image access.

Comment: @HelpingHands in my current htaccess file contains the expire headers code and all other stuffs related to W3TC. so if i replace the htaccess file then my site will take much time to load and i am scared about if it will be reset my W3TC settings which i have done.

Comment: I understand but that is for only testing purpose and to find exact issue , after that you can put back that original htaccess file.